# Ruby socket server thread question: how to send to all clients?

Tags: ruby

I'm making a TCP socket server(ruby). A thread is created for each connected client. At some point I try to send data to all connected clients. The thread aborts on exception while trying.(ruby 1.8.7)

```
require 'socket'
# I test it home right now
server = TCPServer.new('localhost', 12345);
while(session = server.accept)
 #Here is the thread being created
 Thread.new(session) do |s|
  while(msg = s.gets)
   #Here is the part that causes the error
   Thread.list.each { |aThread|
    if aThread != Thread.current
     #So what I want it to do is to echo the message from one client to all others
     #But for some reason it doesn't, and aborts on the following string
     aThread.print "#{msg}\0"
    end
   }
  end
 end
Thread.abort_on_exception = true
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of exception are you getting?

Comment: The program simply aborts without any explanations.

Comment: 'accept' returns an array, so why not try 'while(session, session_sockaddr = server.accept)' to clearly separate the socket from the sockaddr string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following PDF discusses socket programming in ruby in detail.  It includes asynchronous handling and goes through a functioning demonstration of a small chat program.

[IBM guide to ruby socket programming](https://www6.software.ibm.com/developerworks/education/l-rubysocks/l-rubysocks-a4.pdf)